# Jquery ajax code and redirection code in one javascript code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am writing a code in javascript (in .aspx page) which will insert values in database using jquery ajax code through webservice and then it will perform redirect operation, but it does not perform redirection .. please tell me if i am doing something wrong in my code ... here is my code ..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function xyz()
   {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST"
         url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime"
   });

   window.location='....location...';

   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `window.location.href` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   function xyz()
   {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST"
         url: "WebService.asmx/InsertRediretTime"
   });

   window.location='....location...';
   return false;
   }
   </script>
```

try this